# am I implemented correctly Insertion sort in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I read about insertion sort, and we can Implement this sorting in many ways, My only expectation from my this post is that whether my implementation can be considered one of the implementation of Insertion sort or not ?

```
  package com.tech.kj.dp;

class InsertionSort1 {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
   int[] array= {20,54,-15,-9,0,45,2,11};
    
    
    for(int index = 1; index < array.length; index++){
     
      int nextElement = array[index];
      for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
        int sorted=array[i];
        if(nextElement<sorted){
          swap(array,index,i);
        }
      }
    }
    show(array);
  }
  
  public static void swap(int[] array,int i,int j){
    if(i==j){
      return;
    }
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  
  public static void show(int[] array){
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        System.out.print(array[i]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
  
}
```

Comment: one suggestion is to implement a function that checks to ensure that the result is sorted correctly.   Another is to keep track of the number of swaps.

Comment: Thanks @MarkLavin for your quick suggestion, the show() method is there to display the result after the sorting.
and if I implement the function that count the number of swap, than what I will achieve from that I mean if I know the number of swaps than how it is relevant with my question?
I wanted to know that can anyone consider my code as one of the Insertion sort implementation or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your code gives the correct result, sorts correctly. It’s not exactly doing an insertion sort the way I understand it. And I believe that it is doing more swaps than necessary.

Example unsorted array: [5, 7, 2].

The first time through the outer loop your code checks that 7 is not less than 5, so those numbers should not be swapped.

The next time you first check that 2 is less than 5, so swap those so you get [2, 7, 5]. `nextElement` is still 2, so next because 2 is also less than 7, you swap 7 and 5. While it does give the correct result, as I said, it doesn’t seem very logical, and as a reader it was hard for me to convince myself that it was correct.

Instead the way I remember to have understood insertion sort: when you find the correct place for the 2 (by determining that it is less than 5), you should copy it out of the array, push 7 and 5 one place to the right and then insert 2 where the 5 was before (index 0) (hence the name insertion sort).

Comment: Great way to teach newbies! @KISHAN - There are some good visualization tools like [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/insertion-sort/visualize/), [this](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/OpenDSA/AV/Sorting/insertionsortAV.html), [this](https://visualgo.net/en/sorting?slide=9) etc. that can be helpful to you.